# Least performance intensive way to show images

Tags: python, c++, image, pygame, raspberry-pi

I have written a python script that is being run on a raspberry pi 4. The script shows images of flowers that are being faded in and faded out.
The script can show multiple images at the same time. The images uses alpha channel.
Like a slideshow that can show multiple cut out images at the same time.
[Crude example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHqqA.jpg) - every flower in the example image is a separate png-file. They can fade independently.

I'm using pygame for handling the display.

Problems

- As of now the script is running to slow. The fade in/out is choppy and the script is just running way to slow. (On my pc it works fine.)
- Lowering pygame.display.set_mode([1920, 1080], pygame.FULLSCREEN) to 1024,720. And the surface resolution from 1920x1080 to 1024x720 significantly enhances performance (still to slow though, and I really need it to be 1080p)

What I need to do:

- show 1920x1080 images with transparent backgrounds
- use low cost hardware that can boot straight into the program
- show on projector using hdmi
- show several images at the same time
- fade in and out images separately

Questions:

- Should/can I optimize the python script further so it will run smoothly on a rasp-pi?
- Should I use an other library than pygame?
- Would it make a big difference if I wrote the code in C++ instead?

This is my python script

```
import random
import pygame
#import file
try:
    from configparser import ConfigParser
except ImportError:
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser  # ver. < 3.0

# instantiate config file
config = ConfigParser()

# parse existing file
config.read('config.txt')

# read values from a section (exmaples)
"""string_val = config.get('section_a', 'string_val')
bool_val = config.getboolean('section_a', 'bool_val')
int_val = config.getint('section_a', 'int_val')
float_val = config.getfloat('section_a', 'pi_val')"""

pygame.init()

# FRAMERATE
# Setup the clock for a decent framerate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

#stuff from config file
howOften = config.getint('intensity', 'howOften')
flowersMax = config.getint('intensity', 'flowersMax')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1920, 1080], pygame.FULLSCREEN)

# create a surface object, image is drawn on it.
imagesSurfaceSizeX = 1920 #1500
imagesSurfaceSizeY = 1080 #850

imagesSurface = pygame.Surface((imagesSurfaceSizeX, imagesSurfaceSizeY), pygame.SRCALPHA)

fps = 60

# Times
timeToShow = config.getint('speeds', 'timeToShow') * fps  # in seconds * fps << How long will a images be shown
timeWait = config.getint('speeds', 'timeToWait') * fps  # in seconds * fps << How long before new image is shown
fadeMax = config.getint('intensity', 'fadeMax')
timeToFadeConfig = config.getint('speeds', 'timeToFade')
timeToFade = (fadeMax / fps) / timeToFadeConfig  # in seconds | (255/fps)/seconds


# LOAD IMAGES
image_temp = list()
images = list()
imagesInFolder = config.getint('intensity', 'imagesInFolder')
for x in range(imagesInFolder):
    imageName = "images/image% s.png" % x
    image_temp.append(pygame.image.load(imageName).convert_alpha())
    images.append(pygame.transform.scale(image_temp[x], (imagesSurfaceSizeX, imagesSurfaceSizeY)))

createImages = False

# Define areas where we will show images
# areaX = [x, y]
area1 = [200-config.getint('disperesness', 'distanceFromCenter'), 100-config.getint('disperesness', 'distanceFromCen>
area2 = [300+config.getint('disperesness', 'distanceFromCenter'), 100-config.getint('disperesness', 'distanceFromCen>
area3 = [250, 150]  # center
area4 = [200-config.getint('disperesness', 'distanceFromCenter'), 200+config.getint('disperesness', 'distanceFromCen>
area5 = [300+config.getint('disperesness', 'distanceFromCenter'), 200+config.getint('disperesness', 'distanceFromCen>
imagesAreas = [area1, area2, area3, area4, area5]

imagesShowing = list()  # a list with all the instances odf images that are showing right now
imagesDelete = list() #list with images that should be deleted


# Create a new instance of class image
def showNewImage():
imagesShowing.append(Image(
    random.randint(0, imagesInFolder-1),  # choose an image
    0,  # how long has the image been shown
    timeToShow + random.randint(0, timeToShow),
    timeWait + random.randint(0, timeWait),
    timeToFade,# fade speed
    0,  # alpha
    random.randint(0,4),  # choose an area to show the image
    ))


class Image:
    def __init__(self, image, timeShown, timeToShow, timeWait, timeToFade, alpha, area):
    self.image = image
    self.timeShown = timeShown
    self.timeToShow = timeToShow
    self.timeWait = timeWait
    self.timeToFade = timeToFade
    self.alpha = alpha
    self.area = area


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while running:

        print(len(imagesShowing))

        #clean surface
        imagesSurface.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))

        for x in imagesShowing:
            # keep track of time shown
            x.timeShown += 1

            # fade out
            if x.timeShown >= x.timeWait + x.timeToShow + (timeToFadeConfig*fps):  # the images have been shown fully
                x.alpha -= x.timeToFade

            # fade in set alpha 0-255 of the surface
            elif x.alpha < fadeMax and x.timeShown > x.timeWait:
                x.alpha += x.timeToFade

            # blit the image on a surface
            imagesSurface.blit(images[x.image], (imagesAreas[x.area][0], imagesAreas[x.area][1]))
            # set alpha
            imagesSurface.set_alpha(x.alpha)
            # blit the surface on the screen
            screen.blit(imagesSurface,(0, 0))

            # flag for deletion
            if x.alpha <= -1:
                imagesDelete.append(x)

        #delete images that ar not visible
        for x in imagesDelete:
            imagesShowing.remove(x)
            imagesDelete.clear()


        #add images
        if len(imagesShowing) < flowersMax and random.randint(0,howOften) == howOften:
            showNewImage()

        # Ensure program maintains a rate of <fps> frames per second
        clock.tick(fps)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        # Esc == Quit
        keysPressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keysPressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            running = False

        # Flip the display
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Done! Time to quit.
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Do you need to blit the surface to the screen for every image? Or could you build the full surface with all the images and then just blit that to the screen once after you've put all images onto it?

Comment: Consider adding the `pygame` tag so the clever folks spot your question

Comment: @MarkSetchell, sounds like calling blit only once would optimize the code. I don't think it'll be enough though, the performance drop going from 0 to 1 flower is significant and blit is only called once at that stage. Tag added! Good thinking.

Comment: Updating a display in real time is hard, that's why gaming machines have GPUs. I'm not sure even C++ will have the performance you're looking for.

Comment: @MarkRansom Gulp! What are my options in your opinion? Full blown pc?

Comment: I don't use /know `pygame` but I suspect it only uses 1 of the 4 CPU cores available in a Pi4, which is not ideal. I think I would try to benchmark how fast the surface can be generated and how fast it can be blitted to the screen, and whether surfaces can transferred efficiently between CPU cores using Numpy/multiprocessing shared memory. If they can, maybe you can have 3 CPU cores generating the next 3 frames into shared memory and 1 CPU core blitting frames onto the screen... I am only guessing, I don't use `pygame`.

Comment: Not sure.  I've always wanted to explore the limits of the pi in that area, but never found the time.

Comment: The intermediate imageSurface is unnecessary. You can set the alpha on the image directly and then blit that to the screen. Also, profiling your code is the way to go: https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/python/snakeviz-visualize-profiling-results-in-python

Comment: It also may be a lot faster if you used convert() instead of convert_alpha(). When you use set_alpha you’re doing it globally. Convert alpha makes a Surface with per pixel alpha, which is inefficient to blit.

Comment: You might want to head over to the pygame community discord to get help on this, I’m not sure it can be really answered in the Stackoverflow fashion.